# backport of importlib for python 2.7 from 3.6

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wish to do something like this in python 2.7 to import module from a file.

(In python 3.6)

```
import importlib.util
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name,filename)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module
```

How can I go about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to fix this:

`import imp
 module = imp.load_source(module_name.split('.')[-1], filename)
 return module`